# PDO connection to an external MySQL database (from AWS) - "SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user"

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, pdo

The setup is as follows: I have two servers, one with AWS and one 'external' one. I want the AWS instance to run a PHP scripts that connects to the external MySQL. I have granted the MySQL user the rights to be approached by the external IP addresses (specified them). The setup works from my local computer using [MySQL Workbench](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL_Workbench) (so that one can connect with an accepted IP address to the external MySQL.

Because AWS has both an elastic IP address and a different IP address for the actual `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`. I have allowed for both to connect at the moment.

```
try {
    $db_ext = new PDO( 'mysql: host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
                               port=3306;
                               dbname=THE_DB_NAME',
                       'THE_USER_NAME', 'THE_USER_PASS' );
    $db_ext->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch( PDOException $e ){
    print $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

Now when I run this it gives an error:

> SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'THE_USER_NAME'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I am puzzled... (also about that it denies access for `'THE_USER_NAME'@'localhost'` and not for `'THE_USER_NAME'@'IP-OF-SERVER-RUNNING-THE-PHP-SCRIPT'`

Comment: you're missing a `'` in the DSN portion... and have you tried eliminating that space between `mysql:` and `host`?

Comment: You were right, I am very sorry. The space between `mysql: host` was the bottleneck. That made it assume it was a localhost.

Answer (score 0):

It was the space between `mysql: host`. So this code works to connect from one machine with another's MySQL as long as the IP address is allowed:

```
try {
    $db_ext = new PDO( 'mysql:host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; 
                              port=3306; 
                              dbname=THE_DB_NAME', 
                       'THE_USER_NAME', 'THE_USER_PASS' );
    $db_ext->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch( PDOException $e ){
    print $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```